# Linear time algorithm to compute cartesian product

Tags: python, algorithm, cartesian-product

I was asked in an interview to come up with a solution with linear time for cartesian product. I did the iterative manner O(mn) and a recursive solution also which is also O(mn). But I could not reduce the complexity further. Does anyone have ideas on how this complexity can be improved? Also can anyone suggest an efficient recursive approach?

Comment: There are `mn` results; the minimum work you have to do is write each result to the output.  So you cannot do better than `O(mn)`.

Comment: No. Cartesian product gives all possible pairs that can be formed by 2 sets, so it is not possible to further reduce it.

Comment: Maybe your interviewer was thinking of using a quantum computer

Comment: Sack the interviewer!

Comment: @gnibbler: I don't know if you meant that as a joke but I am pretty sure a quantum computer couldn't do any better

Comment: Maybe it was a trick question that was supposed to prompt you to display a proof of the minimum bound of the complexity.

Comment: Both your solutions are linear in size of the output...

Comment: The correct response to "give me a linear time algorithm for XYZ" is "linear *in what*?".

Answer (score 4):

There are `mn` results; the minimum work you have to do is write each result to the output. So you cannot do better than `O(mn)`.

Answer (score 0):

The question that comes to my mind reading this is, "Linear with respect to what?"  Remember that in mathematics, all variables must be defined to have meaning.  Big-O notation is no exception.  Simply saying an algorithm is O(n) is meaningless if n is not defined.

Assuming the question was meaningful, and not a mistake, my guess is that they wanted you to ask for clarification.  Another possibility is that they wanted to see how you would respond when presented with an impossible situation.