# Algorithm for Looping in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, loops

So I have these 2 arrays:

```py
keyword = ['enroll', 'design']
synonym = [
    ['enroll', ['inscribe', 'enter', 'register']], 
    ['design', ['plan', 'blueprint']]
]
```

If I combine the `keyword`, the output is:

```
enroll, design
```

I want to make combination of these `synonym` based on `keyword`, so the output would be:

```
inscribe, plan<br>
inscribe, blueprint<br>
enter, plan<br>
enter, blueprint<br>
register, plan<br>
register, blueprint<br>
```

But I still confuse the algorithm for looping the array. Is there any idea?

Comment: Why isn't `synonym` a dictionary?

Comment: Are there always two keywords? Are the keywords guaranteed to be in the synoynms?

Comment: What's the difference between dictionary and array? Sorry I'm new in Python

Comment: dictionary is key-value pairs. list (not array) is only values

Comment: The amount of keyword is random, but the keywords are guaranteed to be in the synonyms

Comment: So do I need to change synonyms into dictionary?

Comment: @vjchrisintha, yep. That will make your code cleaner. Check my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is an explanation of getting the desired result using python inbuilt modules! You are looking for `python itertools`. The algorithm is being used in the implementation is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960583/efficiency-of-pythons-itertools-product)

With the help of that same module you can follow the below method.

```
import itertools

keyword = ['enroll', 'design']
synonym = [ ['enroll', ['inscribe', 'enter', 'register']], ['design', ['plan', 'blueprint']] ]

synonym_dict = dict(synonym)
data = list(synonym_dict.values())

print(list((itertools.product(*data))))
```

Output of this is:

```
[('inscribe', 'plan'), ('inscribe', 'blueprint'), ('enter', 'plan'), ('enter', 'blueprint'), ('register', 'plan'), ('register', 'blueprint')]
```

Comment: What's the point on repeating the same answer I've already posted?

Comment: I think we both were writing this answer at the same time !. I have seen your answer after submitting mine! This is neither a copy nor an inspiration from your work!

Comment: This worked! But may I ask what is the function of (*) in *data?

Comment: Here,`*` is used for unpacking the list `data` !

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a dictionary because you will want to lookup the keywords in the synonym list

```
keyword = ['enroll', 'design']
synonym = {'enroll' : ['inscribe', 'enter', 'register'], 
           'design' : ['plan', 'blueprint']
           }

combos = []

for i in range(0, len(keyword)):  # for each keyword
    s1 = synonym[keyword[i]]      # get its list of synonyms
    for j in range(i+1, len(keyword)):  # for each following keyword
        s2 = synonym[keyword[j]]       # also get its list
        # create collection of each
        for v1 in s1:
            for v2 in s2:
                combos.append((v1, v2,))
print(combos)
```

#### Output

```
[('inscribe', 'plan'),
 ('inscribe', 'blueprint'),
 ('enter', 'plan'),
 ('enter', 'blueprint'),
 ('register', 'plan'),
 ('register', 'blueprint')]
```

Comment: I tried this, but when the keyword is more than 2 (keyword = ["A", "B", "C"]) it only showed 2 combination

Comment: Your quesrtion only had two. How was I supposed to know you wanted more?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have two separated lists for that. Just use one dictionary where keys are the keywords and values are the synonyms:

```py
synonyms = {
    'enroll': ['inscribe', 'enter', 'register'], 
    'design': ['plan', 'blueprint']
}
```

And then you can combine them using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
from itertools import product

synonyms = {
    'enroll': ['inscribe', 'enter', 'register'], 
    'design': ['plan', 'blueprint']
}

combinations = list(product(synonyms['enroll'], synonyms['design']))
```

And here is a proof of concept:

```py
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2019, 12:16:48) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from itertools import product
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> synonyms = {'enroll': ['inscribe', 'enter', 'register'], 
...            'design': ['plan', 'blueprint']
...            }
>>> 
>>> pprint(list(product(synonyms['enroll'], synonyms['design'])))
[('inscribe', 'plan'),
 ('inscribe', 'blueprint'),
 ('enter', 'plan'),
 ('enter', 'blueprint'),
 ('register', 'plan'),
 ('register', 'blueprint')]
>>>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: What if I had more than 2 keyword?

Comment: @vjchrisintha, Just add it to the dictionary with its corresponding list of synonyms. The answer was based on the example you posted. And if you have more than two keywords, what would be the desired output? You need to clarify that as well.

Comment: Sorry, should have clarify that. Regardless, thank you for the dictionary, appreciate it.