# What is the best way [best time complexity] to generate all binary masks of given length in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I want to generate all binary masks of given length, i.e. for n = 3 I'd like to generate
000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111.

My current code looks likes this, pretty old style, can't figure out how to do the same with f-strings or something cool instead of zfill.

```
for i in range(2**n):
    print(bin(i)[2:].zfill(n))
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica the question was about performance. Here I spend n log(n) to convert into binary and then to zfill on each number, in total that makes n log(n) 2^n. I wonder if it could be done faster. Ideally, 2^n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve the efficiency of your existing code by using a range from `2**n` to `2**(n+1)` and taking the substring from one further character. This removes the need to zero fill:

```
n = 3
for i in range(2**n, 2**(n+1)):
     print(bin(i)[3:])
```

Output

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it with itertools.

```
from itertools import product

for t in product(('0', '1',), repeat=3):
    print(''.join(t))
```

The complexity of calling `product()` is `O(1)`, because it's a generator, so nothing happens until you iterate.

The complexity of the actual `product()` function is discussed here: [efficiency of Python's itertools.product()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960583/efficiency-of-pythons-itertools-product)

Comment: But running the loop is not O(1) because the generator actually runs...