# Convert two string arrays into nested objects

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to take two arrays (in this case, they are arrays of integers), and "Cartesian Product" them into nested objects, in both directions. I am not sure if this a more of a permutation issue, but I get the feeling it involves some usage of methods on the array prototype. For example:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = [4, 5, 6];

function doCartesian(a, b) {
    // logic here
}

console.log(doCartesian(a, b))
// prints out
{
    "firstWay": {
        "1": {
            "4": true,
            "5": true,
            "6": true
        },
        "2": {
            "4": true,
            "5": true,
            "6": true
        },
        "3": {
            "4": true,
            "5": true,
            "6": true
        }
    },
    "secondWay": {
        "4": {
            "1": true,
            "2": true,
            "3": true
        },
        "5": {
            "1": true,
            "2": true,
            "3": true
        },
        "6": {
            "1": true,
            "2": true,
            "3": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like an assignment. What have you tried?

Comment: If each array is length n then the desired output is itself size n².  So unless you don't actually need to output the whole thing, you're not going to do any better than O(n²).  If the question is about complexity then it seems to be [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079069/linear-time-algorithm-to-compute-cartesian-product).

Comment: I am not talking about space complexity, hence your output comment isn't an answer. I am talking time complexity, if there is a way to linearly populate the nested object above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want. I hope i help you

```
function certesian(a,b) {
    var obj = {};
    a.forEach(function(valA) {
        var temp = {};
        b.forEach(function(valB) {
            temp[valB] = true;
        });
        obj[valA] = temp;
    });
    return obj;
}
function doCartesian(a, b) {
    var obj = [];
    obj['firstWay'] = certesian(a,b);
    obj['secondWay'] = certesian(b,a);
    return obj;
}

var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [4, 5, 6];

console.log(doCartesian(a,b));
```